# How can I accelerate a series of similar queries in the datastore of activepivot?

Tags: performance, prepared-statement, activepivot

In my activepivot solution, I have a store containing the desk and the currency for each trade.

For example:

- 1, eur, DeskA, 10
- 2, eur, DeskB, 18
- 3, gbp, DeskA, 17
- 4, usd, DeskA, 54

I have a lot of queries where I want to find all the records
that contain deskA and a particular but changing currency.

To execute those three queries :

- DeskA, eur
- DeskA, usd
- DeskA, gbp

I would use a prepared statement to avoid parsing the query many times.
Is there any equivalent in activepivot ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can define the precompiled query

```
IRecordQuery query = new RecordQuery("storeName", Equal("attributeUsedForSearchHere").parametrized(0), Arrays.asList("attribute2", "attribute3", "attribute4"));
compiledQuery = datastore.getQueryManager().compile(query);
```

This is how you can execute it

```
ICursor cursor = datastore.getQueryManager().execute(compiledQuery , new Object[] { valueOfAttributeUsedForSearchHere} );
```

basically above you use attributeUsedForSearchHere as an attribute that you'll use for search based on an equal condition; of course you may have several attributes.

then once the query is executed you can read the other attributes (attribute2, 3 and 4) like follows:

```
cursor.getRecord().read("attribute2")
```